# Correct format of data to send at services endpoint to create node

Tags: services

I have set up a services endpoint using services module and I am using Mozilla Poster add on to test it. I was able to create a user by sending data from Mozilla Poster in x-www-form-urlencoded format with parameter names "name", "pass" and "mail". Now I am trying to create a node but it is showing the error: "Title field is required".

What should be the parameter name for title field to be sent to the services endpoint? I tried using "title", "field_title" etc but it is not recognizing it. There is a nice tutorial [here](https://drupal.org/node/1354202) to determine data structure to be sent to create a node at remote website. But this tutorial tells how to send data in json format. I want to send data in x-www-form-urlencoded and create a simple node. The HTML code of title field of node create form at my remote website is:

```
<input class="text-full form-text required" id="edit-title-field-und-0-value" name="title_field[und][0][value]" value="" size="60" maxlength="255" type="text">
```

Kindly help me to figure out correct format to send title value in x-www-form-urlencoded format from Mozilla Poster in order to create a node.

Comment: Use postman extension on Google-chrome.

Comment: hello sir, thank you very much for your help. I tried postman extension also but it is throwing the same error "title field is required". What should be the "key" for node title? I tried entering "title", "field_title", "title_field" etc. None is working. How to determine "key" of the remote node field? Please help. I could not find any guide anywhere about this.

Comment: please can you specify all the machine-names of fields you have in your content-type? of which you want to create node.

Comment: Sir @shrish , right now I want to post a simple node with only "title" field and machine name of that field is "title_field". I tried "title_field" as key but it did not work. Please guide sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the html code of node add form as provided by you, title field has name "title_field[und][0][value]". You have to use exactly this name/key in your POST request. Along with that, you also need to send a value with name/key "title". Both needs to be sent. However the value of "title_field[und][0][value]" will be filled as title in the created node.

Comment: woha! This worked. Any specific reason for sending "title" as well as "title_field[und][0][value]"?